# Can't type spaces in right aligned text field in pdf form

Tags: acrobat

I am creating fillable PDF form using adobe acrobat. 
When I choose right alignment for a text field; I can't type spaces between the words when I fill the form. (so the spaces don't appears)

However when I enable the "Multi- line" option or the "Scroll long text" option, I am able to type spaces ! In addition after I finish typing my words and then go back to insert the space, the space appear !

I am using adobe acrobat 9 and my form is generated based on word document.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem--it's inconsistent and a bit buggy. Until they fix it, I recommend just enabling the "Scroll long text" option.